# the if satement does not work with my grammar

Tags: c, if-statement, antlr, grammar, antlrworks

I have an issue with my if statement with my grammar, wich can be found here http://sd-g1.archive-host.com/membres/up/24fe084677d7655eb57ba66e1864081450017dd9/CNew.txt . When I type for example in Ctrl+D :

```
  int k = 0;
  if ( k ==0 ){
       return k;
  }
```

the tree parser stops at "if(" , and the console does not state any reason. Does anyone know where the issue may comes from please ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say it, yes it is in C.

Comment: Can you post your compiler and error please ?

Comment: Here is what I have http://i.imgur.com/8bvmxL6.png , but the console does not state any error. It just stops like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the entry point of your grammar is `translation_unit`, it looks like the parser simply stops after it matched a single `external_declaration`. Try adding the `EOF` (end of file) token at the end of that rule so that the parser is forced to match the entire input:

```
translation_unit
    : external_declaration+ EOF
    ;
```

However, I don't see how an `external_declaration` would ever match an `if`-statement (a `selection_statement`) in your grammar. Perhaps you want to add a `statement` to your `external_declaration`:

```
translation_unit
scope Symbols; // entire file is a scope
@init {
  $Symbols::types = new HashSet();
}
    : (external_declaration)+ EOF
    ;

external_declaration
    : function_definition
    | declaration
    | statement
    ;
```

after which your input will get properly parsed.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is EOF a lexer rule that must be implemented in the grammar too ? Because if I add only this I have thes errors 
[16:40:00] warning(105): CNew.g:35:28: no lexer rule corresponding to token: E
[16:40:19] Note: C:\output\CNewParser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[16:40:19] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Comment: when I add EOF a the end of translation_unit I get the errors mentionned before, but there is a new child from translation_unit which is "MissingTokenException(at if) "

Comment: When I add `EOF` to `translation_unit` of [your grammar](http://sd-g1.archive-host.com/membres/up/24fe084677d7655eb57ba66e1864081450017dd9/CNew.txt), I don't get an error like *"no lexer rule corresponding to token"*. If you do, then you're not using the grammar you linked to in your question. There *is* another error though, but that is just because `external_declaration` will never match an `selection_statement`.

Comment: As for the "no lexer rule" I am really sorry I did not noticed it was done while I was writting it (shame on me) . Anyway Thanks again @Bart Kiers, you are right  the selection_statement could not be reached from the external_declaration block.